# iframe dynamic height doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe

I created a small widget which is basically a php file which contains an HTML AJAX based form. The form's height depends on the output of the AJAX response text.
Therefore, I need to change the height dynamically.
I tried to do that with some code and it works really well BUT only on localhost file.
This code works:

```
<iframe src="ajax/cfw.php" id="idIframe" width="400px" onload="iframeLoaded()" style="border: none;"></iframe>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function iframeLoaded() {
      var iFrameID = document.getElementById('idIframe');
      if(iFrameID) {
            // here you can make the height, I delete it first, then I make it again
            iFrameID.height = "";
            iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
      }   
  }
</script>
```

However when I try to do an iframe of the exact file I pointed on my localhost which doesn't hosted on my localhost it doesn't work:

```
<iframe src="http://website.com/ajax/cfw.php" id="idIframe" width="400px" onload="iframeLoaded()" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

Why is that, and how can I fix it ?
Thanks.

Comment: iFrames have really strict rules. If the iFrame is from another host and has not explicitly given your hostname permission to access it, you can't read nor write anything from the iFrame.

Comment: It is a security issue. You can't get the contents of a remote host from an iframe

Comment: Please be more explicit than "it doesn't work". Does the request return a non-200 response? Does your onload handler not fire? Try using some developer tools in the console to get a little more information.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply.
How can I permit an access to the iframe information ?